# Store Image via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, upload

I have a upload image function via `<input type=file>` function.

This is my script

```
 function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();


            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.prw_img').attr('src', e.target.result).width(112).height(112);

                };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

My HTML code is

```
    <img  class= "prw_img" style="width:112px;height:112px;"/>

    <input id="file" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" name="files[]">
```

I am having a preview of the image in that `<img>` tag. Is there a way to save this uploaded image to my system

Here's the [**BIN**](http://jsbin.com/ojaxib/1/).

And Also i don't want to popup a save as dialog box to be open. Is there the way to store the image in a database

Comment: So you want to save it back on the same device it was loaded from?

Comment: @Musa  a database will be more effective here

Answer (score 0):

Your JS should look like below. It uses AJAX upload

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){

    var input = document.getElementById("file");
    var formdata = false;
    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData();
    }
    input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {

        var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            file = this.files[i];

            if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                if ( window.FileReader ) {
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                        //showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }

                if (formdata) {
                    formdata.append("image", file);
                }




                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "upload.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formdata,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (res) {
                            alert('success');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Not a vaild image!');
            }   
        }

    }, false);


});
```

PHP - upload.php - retrive the data as below at the php level

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

Comment: is there a way to store the image to a database using script or jquery

Comment: When jQuery AJAX hits the php file it will store the image to the database. Actually store the path to the image in the database not the picture

Comment: I need to store that image to my database for further functions. Any ideas for doing that

Comment: Usually we don't store the image in the database. It's not the way. Store the Image path  where the files are uploaded. Then when you need it retrive the file. Hope you know how to upload and retrive a file using PHP. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Answer (score -1):

So far i know, javascript can't do it alone. Then it will be big security hole. You must need to use PHP/other support language beside it.